# Why aren't quoted links consistently converted to hyperlinks?

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

When reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257524/how-to-solve-content-type-error-with-microsoft-bot-framework), I noticed a link that is not a link:

[image: Not a link]

However, the link does get rendered correctly in the edit mode preview:

[image: Edit mode preview]

This seems to indicate two problems:

1. Quoted links don't get converted to hyperlinks correctly
2. The edit mode preview doesn't provide an accurate impression of how the post will render

Can someone please fix both of these problems? Thank you.

Here's a test to see if it happens on "https://meta.stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Quoted text was meant to turn into a hyperlink??

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  Just because the text is in a quote it shouldn't prevent that from parsing the vanilla link.

Comment: You can always force a bare link by surrounding it with `<` `>`: `"<https://meta.stackoverflow.com>"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - What does that have to do with my bug report?

Comment: Since people are upvoting Makoto's "Quoted text was meant to turn into a hyperlink??" it sounds like they're not the only one who misunderstood in that way. I thought my bug report was clear because it always says "quoted links" and never says "quoted text." If people are interpreting my bug report to be suggesting that any text in quotes should be turned into a hyperlink, can you tell me how to word this more clearly?

Comment: @KyleDelaney It’s a workaround.

Comment: Isn't, in general, the whole point of quoting to *prevent* interpretation? What is the point of enclosing a link in quotes anyway? I definitely agree your second point is a bug though.

Comment: The disparity between the local and remote Markdown parsers is known, documented and frankly hilarious. The real question ought to be what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @Nick - I have no idea why that SO user decided to enclose the link in quotes, but it seems like it's just a language thing. It was a link that was meant to be opened in a browser and not an API endpoint or anything, so it certainly seemed like it should be a hyperlink. I don't think we can assume that in general the whole point of quoting is to prevent interpretation. I use backticks when I want to show that a URL is not meant to be opened in a browser.

Comment: @BoltClock - I'm very curious about this. Why is there a local and a remote Markdown parser? If the disparity is documented, can you link to it? I would think that a good solution to problem #2 is to have both cases use the same Markdown parser.

Comment: Now also reported on MSE: [Question URL with quotes displays the actual question title during the edit preview, but not when the edit is saved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363801/289905).